# katzer cordova-plugin-email-composer collapse bottom navbar jQuery Mobile 1.4 cordova 3.x.x

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

using:

- cordova 3.x.x with katzer cordova-plugin-email-composer
- jQueryMobile 1.4
- iPhone 5 iOS 7 real device

plugin works fine but after sending email, when back to App, the bottom Navbar disappears, leaving a 15px gray horizontal bar. Bar grows 15px circa every time you send an email.

Any ideas how to show up the bottom Navbar again after sending email?